# Why BUNDLE_DIR_NAME of webpack is shown wrongly ?

Tags: django, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-4, django-webpack-loader

I'd like to use `webpack` in `Django`
Then, I set up like this.

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT' : {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'front/bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'front/webpack-stats.json'),

    }
}
```

However, Request URL indicates strange URL I don't want

[image]

Taking `static` off in `url` will be perfect, How can I do this?

Comment: what is your webpack config file? To be more precisely your publicPath.

Comment: Also, you public path on your server too